# to show all the slides in one screen by slickslide

Tags: slick.js

I have a problem with slick slides

1. I have only three slides, and all the three slides must be shown. I used slidesToShow:3, but it didn't work and I still don't know why.
2. I want to make those three slides to be shown just like when we use display:flex;justify-content:space-beween; to normal codes and I don't know how.

Could anyone help me with figuring them out?

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  draggable: false,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.content_slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="content_slider slider01">
    Slide 1
  </div>
  <div class="content_slider slider02">
    Slide 2
  </div>
  <div class="content_slider slider03">
    Slide 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not linking the style file of slack properly.

See the implementation below and follow the official doc of slack for reference:
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
});
```

```css
.slider .content_slider {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="content_slider slider01">
    Slide 1
  </div>
  <div class="content_slider slider02">
    Slide 2
  </div>
  <div class="content_slider slider03">
    Slide 3
  </div>
   <div class="content_slider slider04">
    Slide 4
  </div>
  <div class="content_slider slider05">
    Slide 5
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to make slider with only 3 slides, and it doesn't work properly when I set the code to show 3 of the slides.

Comment: Also, if you add the code about flex inside the content, then the flex system will be adapted to the children of the content , not the content itself